# How to use *ngFor for each my category

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Can anyone help me out for this. I have four label tabs and these tabs will have projects. I want when a project is saved this have to be in the same tab i opened the dialog to save the project not in all my tabs.
Hope you will help me out with these.

```
<label for="tab-one">PROPOSITIONS
<a class="plus" 
(click)="opentestdialog('PROPOSITIONS'); false">+</a>
</label>

<div *ngFor="let project of projects$ | async; let i = index;">
```

This opens the dialog it is in typescript.

```
opentestdialog(category) {
this.dialog.open(TestdialogComponent, { data: category });
}
```

And this is the dialog that saves the project

```
   save() {
    if ( this.newProjectName.length > 0) {
    this.working = true;
    const newProject: Project = emptyProject();
    newProject.name = this.newProjectName;
    newProject.id = Math.random().toString();
    newProject.state = this.newState;
    newProject.type = this.newType;
    newProject.category = this.category;
    this.store.dispatch(new UpsertProjectInternalAction(newProject));
    this.newProjectName = '';
  }
```

}
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's everyone that looked my Question and didn't answer.
I found the solution for this.

```
getProjectOfCategory(category: string) {
return this.projects.valueSeq().filter(project => category === 
project.category).toArray();
}
```